# How can I set the navigator locale from mobile

Tags: javascript, date, navigator

I am trying to test a utility function I built for displaying a timestamp in a chat.  I want it to be accessible from every country and dynamically render based on the navigator.language.

I am having issues testing it on mobile.  On desktop I can edit the default language in Chrome's advanced settings.  Do you know where this gets pulled from on mobile and if so where I can change it.

```
export function getLocaleTimestamp (showSeconds) {
  const locale = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  const date = new Date();
  let localeFormat = null;
  const options = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    ...(showSeconds && { second: 'numeric' })
  };
  localeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale,
    options
  ).format;
  const formatedDate = localeFormat(date);
  return formatedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue a while ago testing a change I made for our USA based client. As Chrome uses the timezone that comes from the operating system, so to do this, I had to change the system date time, and also connected to USA VPN. So I assuming it take IP connected/ or network timeline as well.
Also worth trying to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ this in Chrome dev tools, new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta' }) //preferedtime zone

Let me know if something else works out for you. :)
Useful links stackoverflow.com/a/16449343/1225070 and stackoverflow.com/a/18612568/1225070

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks for the recommendations.